# i am trying to destroy session of user by clicking logout button its works their is a issue i have to press twice in order to logout/destroy session

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to destroy session of a user by clicking logout button it works there is a problem I have to press twice in order to log out/destroy the session.
any kind of help will be appreciated.
using following code

```
 <form role="form" method="post">
     <div class="pull-right-container">
         <i class="icon fa fa-user">
             <input type="submit" value="logout"  class="btn btn-danger" name="logout" 
onclick="sessionend()" >
         </i>
     </div>
 </form> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function sessionend()
     {
     <?php
         if (isset($_POST["logout"]))
         {
             session_destroy();
         }
     ?>
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: thats not how it works. `session_destroy()` is a php function to be executed on the web server backend. you need to come up with an http call to trigger it, not just add it in the browser executed javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for onclick() in submit button. Try the following code:-

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ["logout"] )) {
    session_destroy();
    $redirectPageUrl= "http://xxxx/home.php";
    header("Location: ".$redirectPageUrl);
}
?>

<form role="form" method="post">
    <div class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="icon fa fa-user"> 
        <input type="submit" value="logout"
            class="btn btn-danger" name="logout" />
        </i>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i don't know how but this is not working in my case. i need to logout by pressing at once.

Comment: what response are you getting?

Comment: same  i have to press twice

Comment: which page do you want to redirect after logout?

Comment: at first noting happened on second attempt sessionend.

Comment: the page is redirecting fine but by clicking twice.

Comment: @Muaz, Try the updated code, I have added code to redirect to home page after destroying the session. You can edit the url of the page where the user should be redirected after logout.

Comment: you're welcome @Muaz, kindly vote up n accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to unset $_SESSION variables, if you have any, then call the function session_destroy(). After doing this, you can try and test for any session variables and possibly add a redirection page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. You need to call the `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()`, I've also added the action to your form, make sure that it will point to the same page where the form is located. Assuming that your page is named logout.php, your form action will point to logout.php. See the code below as an example.

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ["logout"] )) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: https://yourpage.com");
}
?>

<form role="form" method="post" action="logout.php">
    <div class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="icon fa fa-user"> 
        <input type="submit" value="logout"
            class="btn btn-danger" name="logout" />
        </i>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i have got the idea what ur trying to say I think there is no need to use action .its working fine without using action.but thanks for ur concern.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make you clear what happens:

When you open your page the first time, **PHP will be immediately executed.**

In your case checking for `$_GET`. Since at this moment $_GET has no values your if block will not be excecuted and PHP prints out nothing.

Your onclick Function look at the moment like this. Blank with no functionality. Take a look at the executed code after opening the first time.

```
OnCkickFn (){

}
```

When you submit now, I think your page is reloading, ***keep the blank Function in mind***, but now having the `$_GET` value.

PHP is now executing immediately your `session destroy`, but returning nothing. Your `onClickFn` is still empty

Now you are thinking that your first click did nothing, but in the back PHP did it before.

When you now click once again your `onClickFn` then the page reloads again an you are seeing the result of `session_destroy` from the last time!

Please use the example of @nandal, (fast and easy) this is the way it is working, or change your code to make an API call (more complex)

Comment: yeah, it works as he guided and thanks for your explanation @Michael